# Bash - Find largest file and print its path

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I need to find the largest file of chosen directory and sub-directories and print the path of that file

I can find the biggest file (I think so)

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

However, I'm stuck on printing the path

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -l | sort -nk 5 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Fails if filename contains space.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do :

```
find . -type f -exec du {} \; | sort -n | awk 'END{$1=""; print}'
```